# How to turn off offering to turn on Google Assistant?

Tags: google-assistant

I know how to turn off google assistant. But many times when I make some move at the bottom of phone screen it show me the dialog to turn on Google Assistant. I do not want to turn in Google assistant. Never ever. I do not want to see that screen asking me if I want to turn on Google assistant on my phone. Is there a way how to stop that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on Android Version 12 was to set the default digital assistant app from Google to None.

This is under Settings >> Apps >> Choose default apps >> Digital Assistant App >> Device Assistant app >> Default digital assistant app

Set to None and the prompts should stop coming up.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. It is non obvious you can change the choice "Google".

Answer (score 0):

In Settings, select Apps and notifications. Click Google Assistant, then click Disable.

Comment: I have it disabled already. I am sorry but I think you do not understand my problem.

Comment: See image in edit please

Comment: @boucekv See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings >> Apps >> Settings gear or 3 dotted menu on top right >> Default Apps >> Assist and Voice Input or Device Assistance app>> Assist App or Device assistance app >> Choose Assist App (none)

source:

https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/273692/stop-google-assistant-from-asking-to-be-turned-on?hl=en

Comment: CHOOSING ASSIST APP TO NONE doesn't help either.